# Insert deleted data, plus some hard-coded values, with output statement

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I want to move rows from one table to another, and `delete from [foo] output deleted.[col] into [bar] (col)` looks like a good option.

But the columns aren't identical. So I want to insert some hard-coded values (and ideally programmatically-determined values) into the destination table.

I set up a couple tables to demonstrate.

```
create table delete_output_test (
    thing1 int not null,
    thing2 varchar(50),
    thing3 varchar(50)
)

create table delete_output_test2 (
    thing1 int not null,
    thing2 varchar(50),
    thing3 varchar(50),
    thing4 int
)

insert into delete_output_test values (0, 'hello', 'world'),
                                      (1, 'it''s', 'me'),
                                      (2, 'i', 'was'),
                                      (3, 'wondering', 'if')
```

Now moving from one table to another works fine if I'm not too needy...

```
delete from delete_output_test2
output deleted.thing1,
       deleted.thing2,
       deleted.thing3
into delete_output_test
       (thing1,
        thing2,
        thing3)
```

But what if I want to populate that last column?

```
delete from delete_output_test2
output deleted.thing1,
       deleted.thing2,
       deleted.thing3
into delete_output_test
       (thing1,
        thing2,
        thing3,
        4)
```

> Incorrect syntax near '4'. Expecting '.', ID, PSEUDOCOL, or QUOTED_ID.

I'm fairly new to SQL, so I'm not even sure what those things are.

So why can't I hard-code a value to insert? Or even replace the `4` with some `select` statement if I want to get clever?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Well, `delete_output_test` doesn't have a column named `4` or `thing4` but `delete_output_test2` does. So you can do this:

```
delete from delete_output_test
output deleted.thing1,
       deleted.thing2,
       deleted.thing3,
       4
into delete_output_test2
       (thing1,
        thing2,
        thing3,
        thing4);
select * from delete_output_test2;
```

rextester demo: http://rextester.com/CVZOB61339

returns:

```
+--------+-----------+--------+--------+
| thing1 |  thing2   | thing3 | thing4 |
+--------+-----------+--------+--------+
|      0 | hello     | world  |      4 |
|      1 | it's      | me     |      4 |
|      2 | i         | was    |      4 |
|      3 | wondering | if     |      4 |
+--------+-----------+--------+--------+
```

Comment: I have no idea why it didn't occur to me to try that. Thanks!

Comment: @JohnCappelletti What do you mean?

Comment: Your solution.  Very consise.  Take the compliment dummy. :)

Comment: @JohnCappelletti Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

The requirement is a little curious, but I think you can do it using a CTE or subquery:

```
with todelete as (
      select dot.*, 4 as col4
      from delete_output_test
     )
delete from todelete
    output deleted.thing1, deleted.thing2, deleted.thing3, deleted.col4
    into delete_output_test2(thing1, thing2, thing3, col4);
```

You need to be sure that `delete_output_test` has space for the additional column.

Comment: this seems to move data in the opposite direction... from delete_output_test2 to delete_output_test. Am I incorrect?